# Set distinct prop for each child in react for animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, state

I made a card component as so:
[image]

and I mapped it thrice.

when clicked the card should open as so:
[image]

I've set an setIsOpen pro for the child to return a boolean whether the card is open or not so I can set the row to have 1 column instead of three.

but if i click on another card while the other one is opened it sets the boolen to false and I would have 3 columns while cards are still open as so:
[image]

any logic turn for this problem?
below is the code:

Card code:

```
export default function CardBox(props) {
    const handleOpen=()=>{
        setIsOpen(!isOpen)
        props.setIsOpen(!props.isOpen)
    }
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
    <motion.div transition={{layout:{duration:1, type:"spring"}}} className={styles.root}>
    <motion.div transition={{layout:{duration:1, type:"spring"}}} 
    layout 
    onClick={()=>handleOpen()} 
    className={[`${styles.card} ${isOpen? styles.orange +" "+ styles.alignStart :'' }`]}
    style={{borderRadius:"1rem", boxShadow:'0px 10px 30px rgb(0,0,0,0.5)'}}>
        <motion.h2 layout="position">
            {props.title}
        </motion.h2>
        {isOpen &&
        <motion.div initial={{opacity:0}} animate={{opacity:1}}className={styles.paragraph} >
            <p>{props.par1}</p>
            <p>{props.par2}</p>
        </motion.div>}
        </motion.div>        
    </motion.div>
  )
}
```

code for index:

```
 <Row className={[styles.row, styles.cardRow]} xl={isOpen ? 1 : 3} sm={1}>
    <Col>
      <CardBox setIsOpen={setIsOpen} isOpen={isOpen} title={"Values"} par1={*** text ***} />

    </Col>

    <Col>
      <CardBox setIsOpen={setIsOpen} isOpen={isOpen} title={"Values"} par1={*** text ***} /> 
    </Col>

    <Col>
      <CardBox setIsOpen={setIsOpen} isOpen={isOpen} title={"Values"} par1={*** text ***} />
    </Col>
 </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an index for each child and pass it to the child as a `prop` from the parent, then define `isOpen` as a state in the parent where it's value is -1 for false and the index of the active child otherwise. Write a function (in the parent) `setChildOpen` and pass it as a prop to the children. Have the children check if `isOpen === index` and have the child component act accordingly instead of your previous true/false options. Your `setChildOpen` should either set `isOpen` to a child's index or -1 if none should be open.

Tl;dr. Elevate state.

Comment: but this will open only one card at a time, right?